# Find a Specific Value in a Populated Databound DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dropdown

Using ASP.NET and C#, How can I find and display in dropdownlist a value coming from a database

for example:

a dropdownlist named DDLDepartment is being populated by a table in database which is the list of Department such as Audit, Leasing and Marketing.

A specific User registers and saved his department as Audit. When he updates profile for example, a page should retrieve his record in Dropdownlist and should display "Audit" in that dropdown.

I used this code but it does not work

```
ddlDepartment.SelectedItem.Text  = ddlDepartment.Items.IndexOf(ddlDepartment.Items.FindByText((myReader["Department"].ToString())));
```

and results to this error:

```
Error   12  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'
```

Comment: In `myReader["Department"]` what are you retrieving a `Text` or a `Value`?

Comment: both sir, the Text and its counterpart value sample: Department with a value of interger (1)

Comment: So, data object `myReader["Department"]` contains `1` as value. Am I correct?

Comment: yes and do on  with other item in that dropdown, I have input also a default item at top with "select dept" with value 0

Comment: `ddlDepartment.Items.FindByValue((myReader["Department"].ToString()).Selected = true;`. This can select the dropdown by value.

Comment: cannot convert bool to string is the error sir

Comment: You have to simple write it down don't assign it to `ddlDepartment.SelectedItem.Text`. It will obviously throw an error.

Comment: where? on page load???

Comment: i need to display it of course in the dropdownlist...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i understand your question wrong but aren't you looking to select a value in a drop down list with a value / text ?

you can do it like this

```
ddlDepartment.SelectedValue = ddlDepartment.Items.FindByText(myReader["Department"].ToString()).Value;
```

Comment: to select the ACTUAL VALUE of user in the dropdownlist. Example, I saved my department to be "Audit", when I update my profile and go to that page, it should load Audit in that particualr dropdownlist. Dropdown is being loaded by an sqldatasource.

Comment: If your drop-down list is populated automatically and myReader["Department"].ToString() represents the value saved for the department "Audit" it will select that value in the drop down list. or how do you populate the drop down list ?

Comment: Yes it is, however I have some METHODS in the system that make that unfit. ddldepartment is related to other dropdownlist. When one value is selected in the department ddl, the other is filtered.

Comment: so i need to get the actual value in the dropdownlist for everything to work fine as it is

Comment: After the items is selected and you need the index value , is the a problem geting it like this ? int DropDown_Index = ddlDepartment.SelectedIndex;